# how to reduce the size on memory of my MAF application

Tags: android, ios, oracle, oracle-maf

I have created a small mobile application using Oracle MAF development is completed. Issue is size of application. My application is a single page application which is showing the output "Hello World" and the size of application after deployment the size of apk file is 30 MB on memory. after installing this app on my phone the size increased to around 90MB. please help me to configure the size of my mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite normal that your application is +30mb. The only way to reduce the size is to deploy in **production mode instead of debug mode**.

The initial size will however always be ±30mb because of the JVM and required libraries.